# unable to click the div button using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to click a button which is actually a div tag. I am unable to click on it.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.qoo10.sg/item/LAPTOP-SCREEN-PROTECTOR-SCREEN-GUARD-FOR-13-14-15-INCHES-2ND/410235318"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('selectArea').click()
```

when i run this  program i go this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div id="ship_to_outer" class="selectArea"> could not be scrolled into view.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this screenshot us tells:

[image: img]

there are 4 elements with class name `selectArea`. And the first one is invisible. That's why you are getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div id="ship_to_outer" class="selectArea"> could not be scrolled into view.
```

So, first of all you have to specify exactly which element you want to click on. For example first dropdown:

[image: img2]

has id, and it could be found like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('inventory_outer_0').click()
```

Comment: Note that assigning call of `click` method to variable is senseless as now `elem` is `None`

Comment: @Andersson nice catch! Thank you for feedback. I have fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 buttons with the same class name `"ship_to_outer"` - the first one is hidden, so you cannot click it. Try below code instead

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="selectArea" and not(@id="ship_to_outer")]').click()
```